# Cannot fetch data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

this is my validation page

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    function error_found(){
      header("Location: login.php");
    }
    set_error_handler('error_found');
    ?>
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['loginbtn'])){
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['pwd'];
    $result=mysqli_query($con,'select * from myguests where email="'.$email.'" and password="'.$password.'"');
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['email']= $email;
        header("Location: welcome.php");
    }
    else
        echo"INVALID ACCOUNT";

    }

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

this is my user profile page

```
<html>
    <body>

    <?php    
     require_once 'valid.php'; 
        session_start();    
    echo"welcome  " .$_SESSION['email'];
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE email=".$_SESSION['email']);
     $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
     echo $userRow;
    ?>
    <br><a href="logout.php">logout</a>
    </body>
    </html>

>
```

> I am not able to fetch the data from the database it shows me the error.I think I made mistake in declaring a session variable to the SQL query

Comment: you forgot to put $_SESSION['email'] in single quotes in select query.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error on your sql.

`$res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE email=".$_SESSION['email']);`

It should be:

`$res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."');`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in commented line check.

```
$res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'"); // this line has an issue with "'" 


<html>
    <body>

    <?php    
     require_once 'valid.php'; 
        session_start();    
    echo"welcome  " .$_SESSION['email'];
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'"); // Missing "'" in query to enclosed parameter.
     $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
     echo $userRow;
    ?>
    <br><a href="logout.php">logout</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```